# Typescript - cannot find accessToken

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am writing a redux-toolkit create function and it is the first time I am using typescript. I fixed the error from yesterday and get directly a new one.
Currently Vs-code underlines accessToken and tells me:

> The  property accessToken does not exist for the User[] type.ts(2339)

I googled this and have found, that I should add the property to the interface but this brought no solution. And I ask myself why typescript says, this would be incorrect, when it works fine without typescript.
Here the current state:

```
type AsyncThunkConfig = {
    state: RootState
}
export const createCardImage = createAsyncThunk<object, object, AsyncThunkConfig>('cardImages/create', async (cardImagesData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user!.accessToken;
        return await cardImagesService.createCardImages(cardImagesData, token);
    }catch (error:any) {
        const message =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString()
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message as string)
      }
})
```

My auth initialstate and slice:

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '');
interface User {
  vorname:string;
  nachname:string;
  username:string;
  email:string;
  street:string;
  number:string;
  plz:number;
  city:string;
  password:string;
  isAdmin:boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
  accessToken?:string;
}
interface InitialState{
  user:User[] | null;
  isLoading:boolean;
  isSuccess:boolean;
  isError:boolean;
  message: string;
  auth?:boolean;
}
const initialState: InitialState = {
    user: user ? user : null,
    isLoading:false,
    isSuccess:false,
    isError:false,
    message:"",
};
```

slice without extraReducers:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        reset: (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = false;
            state.isError = false;
            state.message = "";
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncThunkConfig` is the third type parameter. You also need to provide types for `Returned` and  `ThunkArg`.

Try something like:

```
const createCardImage = createAsyncThunk<
  // Returned
  void, // whatever your return type is
  // ThunkArg
  CardImagesData, // the type of cardImagesData
  AsyncThunkConfig
>
```

Comment: @dermek Thanks for your response. I have tried it, but now I have even more errors. What I write must be the wrong syntax.

Comment: You only have to provide the types. So instead of `<response.data:object, cardImageData:object, AsyncThunkConfig>` try `<object, object, AsyncThunkConfig>` or if that does not work `<any, any, AsyncThunkConfig>`.

Comment: We are getting closer. VS-code only underlines thunkAPI and tells: Parsing error: Type expected. It was only a moment, now it is again unknown.

Comment: It's hard to tell whats wrong without a full working/failing example. I noticed that you also added a type to thunkApi in your code in`async (cardImagesData:object, thunkAPI:AsyncThunkConfig,)`. You should not need type annotations there - those should both be inferred (and it's `GetThunkAPI<ThunkApiConfig>`).

Comment: It tells me either (parameter) thunkAPI: GetThunkAPI<AsyncThunkConfig>. So perhaps the content of thunkAPI is wrong. But it should get the jwt token and that is a string. When I pass in accessToken: string, then it gives an Error on AsyncThunkConfig. I get rid of the type annotations. There are not needed.

Comment: can you add `RootState` where are you getting that from,is it from combineReducers or others??