# Why dispatch register function with typescript expects no argument?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

After writing a mern-stack without typescript, I currently writing a webshop with typescript. I have a register-page and try to send the data out of the user-entry via redux-toolkit to the backend, in which I have the crud operations, that all are working well. I tested this with postman. But typescript don't want to send this data. It tells me:

> 0 arguments expected but received 1.ts(2554)

I read both documentations. Usage of typescript in redux-toolkit and typescript with react. I googled the error either, but there seems to be no solution, that explains me the behaviour of typescript.
That is the register page:

```
const Register = () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const selector = useAppSelector((state:RootState)=>state.auth);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formdata, setFormdata] = useState({
        vorname:"",
        nachname:"",
        email:"",
        street:"",
        number:"",
        plz:"",
        city:"",
        username:"",
        password:"",
        password_confirm:"",
    })
    const {vorname, nachname, email, street, number, plz, city, username, password, password_confirm} = formdata;

    const {user, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, message} = selector;

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(isError){
            toast.error(message);
        }
        if(isSuccess || user){
            navigate('/login');
        }
        dispatch(reset);
    }, [dispatch, isError, isSuccess, navigate, user, message])

    const handleChange = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
        setFormdata((prevState)=>({
            ...prevState,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }))
    }
    const onSubmit = (e:React.FormEvent)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(password !== password_confirm){
            toast.error("Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
        } else{
            const userData = {
                vorname,
                nachname,
                email,
                street,
                number,
                plz,
                city,
                username,
                password,
            }
            dispatch(register(userData))//here it not wants to have an argument
        }
    };
```

That is this register in the slice, that should get the data:

```
export const register = createAsyncThunk('/auth/register', async (user, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        return await authService.register(user!);
    }catch (error:any) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message as string)
    }
})
```

That is the http request in the authService:

```
const register = async (userData:object) => {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL + 'register',userData);

    if(response.data){
        localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(response.data))
    }
    return response.data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give type for the user with out it will create void function. this should work. replace `user:UserData` with your type.

```
type UserData = {}  // your data type you want to pass 
export const register = createAsyncThunk('/auth/register', async (user :UserData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        return await authService.register(user!);
    }catch (error:any) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message as string)
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your response. How I should pass it in the type. I tried now type userData = {user:object}. And I tried type userData= {userData: object}. But that throws the error: The userData property is missing in type { firstname: string; Last Name: String; email: string; street: string; number: string; ZIP: String; City: string; username: string; password: string; }", but is required in type userData.ts(2345)
authSlice.ts(36, 18): "userData"

Comment: I think the solution is: async (user:object, thunkAPI). Now there is no error shown anymore. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me with this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139866/typescript-cannot-find-accesstoken